# PHP XML simple_load id

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How do I parse "id" from the following event

```
<event id="100990">
   <title>myTitle</title>
</event>
```

I parse the title like this:

```
$xml->event[0]->title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method of SimpleXML

```
$id_attribute = (string)$xml->event[0]->attributes()->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You [access attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-4723) just like you would access elements of an associative array:

```
$xml_node['id'] // The value of the attribute `id` of the node `$xml_node`
```

The returned value is an object (with a `__toString` method), so you may want to typecast the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php